# Будут ли приложения собранные в XCode 5 запускаться и идти корректно на девайсах с ios 5 и 6

Tags: ipad, ios, iphone

Друзья! Помогите советом - я никак не могу вкурить - в xcode 5 собранные мной приложения будут идти на девайсах на которых стоит ios 6 или ios 5?

Comment: Да, будут. Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Все получается пока собираю приложение на xcode 4.6.3
Сейчас загрузил xcode 5 и обозревая его - задался этим вопросом )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажите нужный iOS Deployment target в свойствах проекта. Соответственно чем значение меньше, тем более старые девайсы будут поддерживаться.

ЗЫ Симулятор запустите соответствующий - работает?

Comment: Ок спасибо!

в build settingв разделе deployment?

Comment: Project -> Info -> Deployment Target -> 5.0

Comment: Ок спасибо за оперативную помощь!

Comment: Удачи в освоении!